# Confluence plugin : how to redirect to existing page

Tags: confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I would like in my blueprint plugin to redirect the user to different/existing page than the one currently created.

Currently my blueprint plugin takes me to a page that is my template.

I'd like it to redirect to an existing page (either in edit mode or view mode).

I feel like this should be possible inside my class that extends AbstractBlueprintContextProvider by using the PageManager. 
It is this class that can detect if it needs to redirect.

Note: I know the URL and the PageID of the page I want to redirect to.